# 299US$ Upgrade for Pro is for 1 site or any domain with my License

Tags: license

I'm not sure 299US$ for Upgrading to Pro License is for 1 domain on upgrading or any domain with my account (Craft CMS Member).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is per domain (excluding sub-domains), i.e. for one domain / website.

domain.com and subdomain.domain.com can both run off of the same license.

[More info](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/license-enforcement) on how that is all enforced.